# SQL update with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

While transferring an existing database from Access to SQL, I'm trying to update a table in SQL called Component, but it is taking duplicates. The query I've written looks like this:

```
update CDB2020.dbo.Components
set PartType_ID = pt.PartType_ID
from CDB2020.dbo.PartType as pt
inner join AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a on pt.Name = a.[Part Type]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType as ct on ct.Name = a.[Component Type]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no];
```

The tables I'm using is created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Components](
    [BK_ID] [nchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nchar](255) NULL,
    [PartType_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Components] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Components]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ComponentsPartType] FOREIGN KEY([PartType_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PartType] ([PartType_ID])
```

The table already holds the `BK_ID`, `Value`, and `Description` data. Now I need to insert the `PartType_ID`.

The table `PartType` is created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartType](
    [PartType_ID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ComponentType_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PartType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PartType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PartTypeComponentType] FOREIGN KEY([ComponentType_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ComponentType] ([ComponentType_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PartType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PartTypeComponentType]
```

Which refers to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComponentType](
    [ComponentType_ID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ComponentType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

The table [B-K Data] in the AccessDataMigration_1 DB is the table holding the information about legal combinations of component ID, part type and component type:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B-K Data](
    [B-K no] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Component Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Part Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The problem is, that when I've used the update query, it creates duplicates. Here, I've used the following select query to demonstrate the problem:

```
Select comp.BK_ID, pt.PartType_ID, pt.Name as PartType, ct.Name as ComponentType
from (((AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as comp on comp.BK_ID = a.[B-K no])
inner join CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType as ct on ct.Name = a.[Component Type])
inner join CDB2020.dbo.PartType as pt on pt.Name = a.[Part Type])

where BK_ID = 'CK0820'
```

[image: Select query result]

As seen from the picture, it knows that the component type is Capacitor, and that the part type is MISCELLANEOUS. However, the PartType_ID have 7(!) different instances, which is because it found 7 different instances where a component type was MISCELLANEOUS.

I want my table to only hold ONE instance with the correct PartType_ID. What am I doing wrong in my Update query?

I've tried changing the update query to the following, but with same results.

```
CDB2020.dbo.Components
set PartType_ID = pt.PartType_ID
from CDB2020.dbo.PartType as pt
inner join AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a on pt.Name = a.[Part Type]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType as ct on ct.ComponentType_ID = pt.ComponentType_ID
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no];
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL is a language, implemented by many products.)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @Ioragi It is just SQL server not the SQL Server Management Studio. Management studio is a separate tool to connect and query on server and the database.

Comment: @loragi . . . Something is wrong with your `join`s -- or your tables have duplicates -- and I don't think your question has enough information for anyone else to decipher this.

Comment: Would I be ableto use some kind of If statements that checks the Access table what kind of PartType and ComponentType a given component is, and based on this, find the corresponding PartType_ID and update the table? If so, can someone give a hint to where I can learn about such an IF statement?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the `JOIN`s don't look right.  For instance you have:

```
CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType ct join
CDB2020.dbo.PartType pt
on pt.Name = a.[Part Type]
```

From what I can tell, though, this should be:

```
CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType ct join
CDB2020.dbo.PartType pt
on pt.ComponentType_ID = ct.ComponentType_ID
```

I can't tell if you have other problems of this sort.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment! 
I'm, not sure where you get that part of the code from - I can't find it in what I wrote. 
But are you saying the fault may lie in the fact that I try to search in the Access table for component type that matches with the name in the ComponentType table?

Comment: I've tried to change the update query (look in the bottom of my post).
However, the same problem occurs.

Comment: @loragi . . . The first code comes from your question, just formatted a little differently.